# Simple Javafx application not launching from eclipse <exit value: -1073740791>

Tags: javafx, launch

This is a frustrating one that i am sure has a simple solution but i can't figure out which setting changed which is causing my javafx application not to launch.

The first javafx application that i ran on my workstation through eclipse oxygen worked fine. I imported a project that was prebuilt to display fractals and added "javafx/**" as accessible to my build path and i was able to launch it successfully.

Since then, I've tried loading other javafx projects to my workspace and running them with the same build path but nothing appears after i try to run the application.

I made sure to be in the class that extends application with the launch in it and that the build path is set but all i get when i try to run it in debug any javafx application terminates right away with the following exit code:

```
<disconnected>org.hameister.javafx.fractal.JavaFXFractal at localhost:49944
<terminated, exit value: -1073740791>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\javaw.exe
```

At first i thought it was the code in the new projects but when i try to run the original fractal project again it gives me the same thing.

Does anyone have a clue how i can fix this?

Thank you!

Update:

I reinstalled the jdk (jdk-8u161-windows-x64) and eclipse (Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)) and am working out of a new workspace.

When I debug the applications, I get a quick stack that displays:

```
-Daemon Thread [QuantumRenderer-0] (Running)
-Daemon Thread [thread-1] (Running
-Thread [WindowsnativeRunLoopThread] (Running)
```

Then the stack is empty with only the terminated exit value from above.

It's as though I hit some hotkey or button that is no longer allowing applications to visually appear.  Console based Java applications run fine.

Comment: Is there any other error message?

Comment: just above the terminated line theres:
<disconnected>org.hameister.javafx.fractal.JavaFXFractal at localhost:49944

Comment: Sorry I just noticed that the exit code wasn't appearing in the OP because of the brackets.